# How to not apply logic in SQL where block to all when blocks

Tags: sql

So I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT column1 
FROM (
  SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN column2 IN (1, 2) THEN 'name2' // line 5
    WHEN column2 IN (3, 4) THEN 'name3' // line 6
    ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
  END AS column1
  FROM table
  WHERE
    column3 IS null
    AND column4=True // line 12 <==== How do I apply this logic to ONLY line 6 and NOT line 5?
  ) AS name4
GROUP BY column1
```

I don't know how to just apply the logic in line 12 to only affect line 6 and not line 5. I've tried:

```
AND column4=True AND column2 NOT IN (3, 4)
```

But this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is close, but it is slightly different:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
         (CASE WHEN column2 IN (1, 2) THEN 'name2' // line 5
               WHEN column2 IN (3, 4) THEN 'name3' // line 6
              ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
          END) AS column1
  FROM table
  WHERE column3 IS null AND
        (column4 = True OR column2 NOT IN (3, 4))
```

Note:  the query in your question can be simplified.  The subquery is unnecessary.

It might be easier to follow the logic as:

```
  WHERE column3 IS null AND
        NOT (column4 <> True AND column2 IN (3, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but shouldn't `(column4 = True OR column2 NOT IN (3, 4)) ` be `(column4 = True OR column2 IN (3, 4)) `? This seems to be working for me.

Comment: @QLiu . . . No.  With that formulation, (false, 3) would match.